# install4j installer does not make the UNIX installer runnable

Tags: install4j

It seems that setting runnable the generated UNIX installer is missing from their Gradle plugin, any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the generated installers executable is generally not a feature in install4j, not just in the gradle plugin.

Comment: I understand it does not, but why? It seems like a must have feature :)

Comment: Usually installers are transferred away from the build machine and the executable flag does not survive that.

Comment: I make my own RPM and Deb Packages for about almost one year and the executable flag survives in this case. You can set the file mode while creating the RPM or the Deb package, it's supported by numerous native build tools. The executable flag might not survive when you decompress an archive.

Comment: @gouessej The question was not about RPM or Deb packages, but related to shell script installers generated by install4j. Could I politely ask you to refrain from making these kinds of comments that do not contribute anything?